# How can I ensure that fields from a Views query plugin work as tokens?

Tags: views, 8

I have a Drupal 7 Views query plugin module that pulls in data from a RESTful API for use in Views. I used this series of articles as a starting point to build it: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/building-views-query-plugins. I now need to port it to Drupal 8.

I have made a start on the porting process, with the help of this series of articles: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/building-views-query-plugins-dupal-8-part-1. The Drupal 8 module now successfully pulls in data for the fields that use the 'standard' handler.

I'm currently stuck on trying to get tokens representing one of those fields to work when rewriting results.

The field is called `access-url` and contains URLs. If I tick 'Override the output of this field with custom text' on that field, and enter the token form, `{{ access-url }}`, it just returns '0' for every record, whereas if I untick that box it returns the URLs correctly. Meanwhile, the token form of the `id` field works correctly.

(In real life I will want to use `{{ access-url }}` under 'Output this field as a custom link', but 'Override the output of this field with custom text' illustrates the problem better.)

How can I get the `{{ access-url }}` token to work correctly?

I expect it would be helpful if I posted some code, but I'm not sure what code would be most helpful, so please let me know.

**Additional debugging info:** as far as I can tell, all seems well until it gets to the line in `PluginBase::viewsTokenReplace()` that runs `$this->getRenderer()->renderPlain($build)`. `$build` at that point has the value of `access-url` in it, but the renderer returns zero.

Comment: Do you have addSelfTokens() and documentSelfTokens() in the field plugin?

Comment: At the moment I'm using the built-in 'standard' field handler. Do you think I would be better overriding it?

Comment: Not all built-in fields implement these methods, only entity fields and 2 or 3 other fields.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a go at that, and let you know how I get on. Thanks!

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. By the time `addSelfTokens()` runs, the correct tokens are already in the `$tokens` array. In fact, all seems well until it gets to the line in `PluginBase::viewsTokenReplace()` that runs `$this->getRenderer()->renderPlain($build)`. `$build` at that point has the value of `access-url` in it, but the renderer returns zero. Any further thoughts on what might be going on would be gratefully received.

Comment: Can you post what is in the inline template you want to get replaced and the key/value by which it should get replaced?

Comment: The inline template contains `{{ access-url }}`, and it should be replaced with e.g. `['@{ access-url }' => 'http://oppla.eu/casestudy/17238']`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, and I think you have a problem with the token key, it should be the plain token name `'access-url'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96645/discussion-between-tom-butlin-and-4k4).

Comment: To make a valid stackexchange question out of this you have to provide all details necessary to reproduce the wrong token key.

Comment: I'm not sure the token key is wrong - see my message in chat. The only way I know of to reproduce the problem in general involves installing my module. I'll think about making it available to download. Many thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I realised that it was only tokens containing hyphens that weren't working, and sure enough, it turns out that hyphens are not allowed in Twig tokens. Or, to be more accurate, they are interpreted as minus signs (https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2371633). That was why the `{{ access-url }}` token was returning zero: access minus url equals zero, apparently. So I just replaced all of the hyphens with underscores.